# What does Doctrine ORM give you that mysqli_fetch_object + some custom code does not?

Tags: php, mysqli, orm, doctrine-orm

Surprised I don't see this asked yet.

What is the difference between `Doctrine`'s `getResult()` and `MySQLi's` `mysqli_fetch_object`?

I was using Doctrine for its power to transform table rows to objects.  But mysqli_fetch_object + a few lines of code can do the very same for me and way more efficiently.

From what I see Doctrine ORM is a Library that does a lot of heavy lifting for you and has some perks.  What all the perks are, I am not sure.  I have been using some of them.  I started using the ORM, thinking it was awesome and it was, but realizing how much more heavy-weight it is.

I started looking into mysqli and see there is a `fetch_object`.  Well what the hey?  What does Doctrine do better?  The only perks I see are

- database engine independence
- auto-boxing-unboxing (table row <=> object)
- associations and updating database SQL from associations
- auto-escaping when using `persist()`

Some actually cool perks are:

- auto-persists to database any changes to the object if it is "managed"
- caches requests so if you hit database with same SQL 1000 times, it only hits database one time

all of the above are great but I am not sure if they are great enough to keep using the ORM....

For this answer I am looking for something I may have missed.  Why have a monster of an ORM when I can declare an object and have `mysqli_fetch_object` do the conversion work?

Note: I can see answers saying `mysqli_fetch_object` is a single method that converts table row to an object for you, and Doctrine ORM is *everything*.  I am looking more for an answer ... what does Doctrine ORM give you that mysqli_fetch_object cannot.

I am thinking of stopping my use of Doctrine and looking for any reasons I may regret doing so later.

**Code**

To show some code

```
/* 
 * Both return an object of class Product
 * 
 * one uses mysqli
 * one used ORM
 */
$r = new Repository();

//outputs product model using MySQLi
//0.130990 sec for 10 runs (XDEBUG + Qcachegrind)
var_dump($r->getProductInfo(1)->getModel());   

//outputs product model using ORM
//3.431963 sec for 10 runs (XDEBUG + Qcachegrind)
var_dump($r->getORMProductInfo(1)->getModel());

//if I run above in a loop some 1000+ times, 
//ORM caches my query and hits DB only once
//while MySQLi has no caching set up
//hence ORM outperforms MySQLi when tests are run with multiple same queries
```

**Repository**

```
class Repository extends GenericRepository
{

    /* 
     * MySQLi with some custom code I wrote
     */
    function getProductInfo(int $productId)
    {
        $sql = "
            SELECT model FROM product WHERE id = ?
            ";
        $result = $this->getLink()->paramQuery($sql, $productId);
        return $result->getSingleObject(Product::class);
    }

    /*
     * Doctrine ORM
     */
    function getORMProductInfo(int $productId)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->find(Product::class, 1);
    }
}
```

**MySQLi Result class**

```
class MySqlResult
{

    /**
     * Get single object
     */
    function getSingleObject(string $className)
    {
        return $this->result->fetch_object($className);
    }
}
```

**Product**

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @Table(name="product")
 *
 * @Entity
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     *
     * @var integer @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *      @Id @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var string @Column(name="model", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $model;
}
```

Comment: Those 4 perks you mentioned plus the fact that `fetch_object` fetches an `stdObject` and not an actual class object, are actually really valuable and make the use of an ORM worth it for most people.

Comment: Thanks.  Although see `MySqlResult::getSingleObject` above.  I can specify and use my own custom object class and fetch data directly into that object.  i.e. the `Product` class object.

Comment: Some other perks from the top of my head: [Type conversion](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html); [Locking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html); [Proxies and Lazy/Eager loading](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html); [Events and lifecycle callbacks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html). But if you are happy with simple objects - keep it simple.